# Help evaluating the following limit please.

Tags: limits

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}\right)$$

I couldn't figure out why the answer is $-1$.

Comment: Did you try rationalizing by turning it into a fraction?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453638/solving-this-limit-without-lh%C3%B4pital/1453641#1453641, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457529/find-the-limit-of-x-sqrtx2-8x-as-x-to-infty/1457587#1457587 OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454627/calculating-lim-x-to-infty-left-sqrt4x2-6-sqrt4x2x-right/1454659#1454659

Comment: Always begin the question by applying limit and understand which form it is this particular problem is in $\infty-\infty$ model so rationalise and apply limit again . You have to be thorough with the three/four basic forms .

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**
Multiply and divide by $$1 = \frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}$$

Note that
$$
\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}\right)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}\right)
$$
is of the form $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$

Comment: Could you please show me more steps, Thanks very much.

Comment: @Itan here is another hint...

Comment: translation: Can you do my homework??

Comment: @imranfat yes, i tried to avoid connecting all the pieces...

Answer (score 0):

Give $\epsilon>0$ however small, there exists $X(\epsilon)$ such that $|x-\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}+1|<\epsilon$ for all $x>X$.

$$|x-\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}+1|<\epsilon$$
$$\Leftarrow x+1-\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}<\epsilon$$
$$\Leftarrow x+1-\epsilon<\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}$$
$$\Leftarrow x^2+2x+1-2(x+1)\epsilon+\epsilon^2<x^2+2x-1$$
$$\Leftarrow \epsilon^2+2<2(x+1)\epsilon$$
$$\Leftarrow \frac{\epsilon^2+2}{2\epsilon}<x+1$$
$$\Leftarrow \frac{\epsilon^2+2}{2\epsilon}-1<x$$

Let $X(\epsilon)=\frac{\epsilon^2+2}{2\epsilon}-1<x$