# How to solve $\lim _{x\to-\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + x - 1} + x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've tried everything with this question, once I multiply by the conjugate I can't simplify very well

$(x-1)/(\sqrt{x^2 + x - 1} - x)$

Then going to this line seems to mess with the limit, although it seems like I've done it right.
$(x-1)/(x(\sqrt{1 + 1/x - 1/x^2} - 1))$

I could also multiply by $(1/x)/(1/x)$ but again I get a similar problem

Once I cancel the $x$'s

$1/(\sqrt{1 + 1/x - 1/x^2} - 1) - 1/(\sqrt{x^2 + x - 1} - x)$

The first fraction becomes undefined

If someone could drop a stepping stone for me it would be very helpful

Comment: I didn't ask this question this way and somebody editted it to be wrong. I said limit as x -> -infinity. not positive infinity.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454627/calculating-lim-x-to-infty-left-sqrt4x2-6-sqrt4x2x-right  OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453638/solving-this-limit-without-lh%C3%B4pital   OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457529/find-the-limit-of-x-sqrtx2-8x-as-x-to-infty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+x-1}+x
    = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{(-x)^2+(-x)-1}+(-x)
    = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-x-1}-x
$$

Does that help?

Comment: I did think about this... I think that one actually equals the negative of the other. I don't know how to use this though. I'm genuinely lost on this question, is there a way to solve it using squeeze theorem?

Comment: No.  I'll elaborate on why this isn't the negative on the other, and then you can can multiply by $\sqrt{x^2-x-1}+x$ over itself.  (I don't mean "no, you can't use squeeze"; I meant that you don't need to.  Sorry!)

Comment: P.S.  If it still confuses you, try with specific large-ish values of $x$ to confirm to yourself that the equality is correct.

Comment: Thanks so much I got -1/2 :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+x-1}+x\right)&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+x-1}+x\right)\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}-x}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{(x^2+x-1)-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x-1}-x}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}-x}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x-1}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}-x}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x-1}{-x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}-x}\\[1ex]
&=-\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}\\[1ex]
\end{align*}$$